# How to create an IAM Policy for a specific Role and give access to s3bucket get and put operations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-policies

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is my amazons3fullaccess policy but now i want to give only get put and delete access not full access

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following using [wildcards](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_action.html):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:put*", "s3:delete*", "s3:get*"],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Or if you want to be more specific (good practice!):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:putObject", "s3:deleteObject", "s3:getObject"],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```